# Which site is a question about how radio signal jammers work best suited to?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have a question regarding how radio signal jammers work and I'm wondering whether it's more suited to 'Electrical Engineering' or 'Physics'.

My question is as follows:

> I understand that radio signal jammers, such as that used to block the signal from an explosives detonator, work by emitting a broad spectrum of powerful radiowaves to drown out those from potential threats. I've also heard that sensitive or poorly built radio triggers are known to have been activated by signals emmited by devices other than that of the intended trigger, such as the signals from police radios. What I am wondering is, with that in mind, what stops the signals from the jammer activating the device?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Amateur Radio](https://ham.stackexchange.com) site may be a good fit for this question.

Looking at what's [on topic](https://ham.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site, it says:

> Questions are expected to be about **Amateur radio specifically,** or the **technology of [radio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio),** or **[Morse code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse_code).**

To me, your question seems to be about the "technology of radio" (as "radio" is defined in the linked Wikipedia page), so I think it would be on topic for this site as-is.

At the bottom of this page, it does say to avoid asking questions about:

> engaging in activities which are blatantly illegal or generally considered harmful (such as radio jamming or transmitting without a required license)

However, your question isn't about the action of jamming, it's about how jamming works, so I don't think this sentence is relevant.

Additionally, there are a handful of [questions about jamming](https://ham.stackexchange.com/search?q=jammer+is%3Aq) on this site that seem to be overall well-received.

---

### Update:

This is also supported by a recent post on their Meta site discussing the OP's question specifically: *[Should we more narrowly define the scope of this stack?](https://ham.meta.stackexchange.com/q/499)*

Comment: *"how radio signal jammers* ***work best"*** (my emphasis) is not far from *"...engaging in activities which are blatantly illegal or generally considered harmful (such as radio jamming or transmitting without a required license"*

Answer (score 3):

> I'm wondering whether it's more suited to 'Electrical Engineering' or
> 'Physics'.

I am active on [EE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/tour), and it would likely be closed with the community-specific reason:

> Questions on the *use* of electronic devices are off-topic as this
> site is intended specifically for questions on electronics *design*.

I am not active on Physics, but I do see tags named [radio](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio) and [radio-frequency](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio-frequency).  However, since those tags have no usage guidance, you should first look at well-received questions before deciding to post.

You could also [search Stack Exchange for "radio jammer"](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=radio%20jammer) and see if any similar types of questions have been asked anywhere.  Nothing jumps out at me.

In its current form, it may not be suitable on any site.  To boost your chances, you could add more details to the question: what jammer device, what frequency band, what range, etc.

Comment: How is a question about how a thing works not a case of a question about designing one? Their "how it works" isn't about how a device is used, it's about device design.

Comment: @philipxy: It is an observation based on my experience.  Another likely close reason is "lacks details".

Comment: You didn't answer the question in my comment. You seem to have answered, why is it off-topic. I expect I would agree that the asker's main site question is way too vague & general. But my comments are about the particular reason quoted in this post not being appropriate.